# SAGE - ODBC via IIS - minimum required folder permissions for ACCDATA folder

Tags: asp.net, security, permissions, odbc, sage

I have a website which I want to connect to SAGE ACCDATA folder (which resides on a different server but same network to the intranet server) using their proprietary ODBC driver.

For security purposes I'm trying to find out the minimum folder permissions that are required in order to allow this connection.

If I give the folder 'Everyone' permission the connection works regardless of the application pool identity, similarly if I give the folder the 'Network' security principal/SID (A group that includes all users who are signed in via a network connection.) the connection works regardless of application pool identity.

I can't seem to find this documented anywhere, indeed the only documentation I can find about ODBC says to give it 'Everyone', nothing that mentions 'Network'!